# How can I make a footer's height expand to take up the remainder of the screen?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm looking to do something like:

[image]

Where I have a footer at the bottom of the page which has a height that expands to take up the remainder of the screen.

Is it possible to do this in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at doing this before and wasn't able to find a way to do it using strictly CSS.  However, I have seen it done successfully using Javascript (the [jQuery CSS height function](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height)).

Answer (score 0):

if your target is to make the footer at bottom.
you can make the footer (DIV) set to

> .footer{position: absolute; bottom:
>   10}

the bottom you need to change the value as needed.